# Best practice for including from include files

Tags: c++

I was wondering if there is some pro and contra having include statements directly in the include files as opposed to have them in the source file.

Personally I like to have my includes "clean" so, when I include them in some c/cpp file I don't have to hunt down every possible header required because the include file doesn't take care of it itself. On the other hand, if I have the includes in the include files compile time might get bigger, because even with the include guards, the files have to be parsed first. Is this just a matter of taste, or are there any pros/cons over the other?

What I mean is:

sample.h

```
#ifdef ...

#include "my_needed_file.h"
#include ...

class myclass
{
}

#endif
```

sample.c

```
#include "sample.h"

my code goes here
```

Versus:

sample.h

```
#ifdef ...

class myclass
{
}

#endif
```

sample.c

```
#include "my_needed_file.h"
#include ...
#include "sample.h"

my code goes here
```

Comment: Good luck compiling a class in C.

Comment: Every include increases compilation time and drags in more identifiers. You want to limit both. If you don't need an include in sample.h for it to work with other_translation_unit.cpp, don't add it to sample.h. And if you think translation times don't matter much, you haven't tried template-heavy C++ headers yet. ;-)

Comment: You include the same headers in both examples, how would compilation time get bigger anyway?

Comment: @JonathanWakely, It's an, ... `example` to demonstrate what I mean...

Comment: But it doesn't demonstrate it!  Do you mean in the case where both `sample.h` and `sample.c` end up saying `#include "my_needed_file.h"`, maybe indirectly? Or where `my_needed_file.h` includes something that another header already includes? e.g. several headers all `#include <vector>`? It's not entirely clear what you're asking about and what you think could increase compilation time.

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant. Obviously I don't want to write 10 include stamtements for an example as we all know how big the list of includes can become, and that there will be includes which may also already be included from somewhere else like string, vector, etc.

Comment: OK, but if there are "includes which may also already be included from somewhere else like string, vector, etc" then they're still included the same number of times in both your examples ... all you've done is move the include directives from one file to another, not reduced the number of include directives (unless there's some other difference you're not bothering to show and think is "obvious"). Anyway, including headers multiple times doesn't affect compilation time with modern compilers, so keep your headers clean and forget about the cost of including things more than once

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's not really any standard best-practice, but for most accounts, you should include what you *really* need in the header, and forward-declare what you can.

If an implementation file needs something not required by the header explicitly, then that implementation file should include it itself.

Comment: On a sidenote: You *should* include everything you need in the header... I really hate it when the inclusion order of headers matters ;)

Comment: @dionadar just make sure you really know what "need" means in this case. You might think you "need" to include a header, when a forward-declaration would do.

Comment: Of course. One of the most fun examples I was thinking of was someone declaring `::std::ostream& operator<<(::std::ostream&, T);` for a bunch of types in our code base... and never including `<ostream>` in the headers where he did it. No problem for him, since he *always* included `iostream` before any other headers...

Comment: @dionadar If you're not actually implementing the `<<` operators in the header (or if the implementation just forwards to a member function which isn't in the header), then you should include `<iosfwd>`, and not the full `<istream>` and/or `<ostream>`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, this is usually my approach. Top make the include as independent as possible.

Answer (score 3):

The language makes no requirements, but the almost universally
accepted coding rule is that all headers must be self
sufficient; a source file which consists of a single statement
including the include should compile without errors.  The usual
way of verifying this is for the implementation file to include
its header before anything else.

And the compiler only has to read each include once.  *If* it
can determine with certainty that it has already read the file,
and on reading it, it detects the include guard pattern, it has
no need to reread the file; it just checks if the controling
preprocessor token is (still) defined.  (There are
configurations where it is impossible for the compiler to detect
whether the included file is the same as an earlier included
file.  In which case, it does have to read the file again, and
reparse it.  Such cases are fairly rare, however.)

Answer (score 2):

A header file is supposed to be treated like an API. Let us say you are writing a library for a client, you will provide them a header file for including in their code, and a compiled binary library for linking.

In such scenario, adding a '#include' directive in your header file will create a lot of problems for your client as well as you, because now you will have to provide unnecessary header files just to get stuff compiling. Forward declaring as much as possible enables cleaner API. It also enables your client to implement their own functions over your header if they want.

If you are sure that your header is never going to be used outside your current project, then either way is not a problem. Compilation time is also not a problem if you are using include guards, which you should have been using anyway.

Comment: Well, of ocurse I only include in a header file what is needed for this particular header. However, when I need i.e. strings and I include `#include <string>` it's very likely that other headers do the same. But on the other hand if I don't include them then SOMEBODY has to include them, thus forcing the user to look up what is needed on his own, instead of having it like a consistent API.

Answer (score 1):

Having more (unwanted) includes in headers means having more number of (unwanted) symbols visible at the interface level. This may create a hell lot of havocs, might lead to symbol collisions and bloated interface

Answer (score 1):

> On the other hand, if I have the includes in the include files compile time might get bigger, because even with the include guards

If your compiler doesn't remember which files have include guards and avoid re-opening and re-tokenising the file then get a better compiler. Most modern compilers have been doing this for many years, so there's no cost to including the same file multiple times (as long as it has include guards). See e.g. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Once_002dOnly-Headers.html

Headers should be self-sufficient and include/declare what they need. Expecting users of your header to include its dependencies is bad practice and a great way to make users hate you.

If `my_needed_file.h` is needed *before* `sample.h` (because `sample.h` requires declarations/definitions from it) then it should be included in `sample.h`, no question.  If it's *not* needed in `sample.h` and only needed in `sample.c` then only include it there, and my preference is to include it *after* `sample.h`, that way if `sample.h` *is* missing any headers it needs then you'll know about it sooner:

```
// sample.c
#include "sample.h"
#include "my_needed_file.h"
#include ...
#include <std_header>
// ...
```

If you use this `#include` order then it forces you to make `sample.h` self-sufficient, which ensures you don't cause problems and annoyances for other users of the header.

Answer (score -1):

I think second approach is a better one just because of following reason.

1. when you have a function template in your header file.

   ```
   class myclass
   {
       template<class T>
       void method(T& a)
       {
          ...
       }
   }
   ```

And you don't want to use it in the source file for myclass.cxx. But you want to use it in xyz.cxx, if you go with your first approach then you will end up in including all files that are required for myclass.cxx, which is of no use for xyz.cxx.

That is all what I think of now the difference. So I would say one should go with second approach as it makes your code each to maintain in future.